# C# script - SQL query best practice

Tags: c#, sql

I have an Excel file with a long list of usernames. Col A contains old user names Col. B has the new names. I want to rename users in a SQL table based on the excel file. My question is the following:
Is it ok to call SQL with a using statement multiple times within a loop where I iterate through the excel? Or is there a better way where I open a single connection and make all the SQL update queries with “one” go?

Comment: Tag the database you're using. It really depends on how large the file is, if it's just a handful of rows then looping over them and updating per row won't be a big deal, if you're talking about 1000s then it would make more sense to pass the list of users to a sql proc and do a single update in the database.

Comment: Heavy database usage is also a factor, you could end up with page or table locks, but it depends greatly on the specific scenario

Comment: This is too broad, you need to include a code example to get a more specific response, otherwise you get "It depends"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is always that *"it depends"* and *"can you justify it"*.
Right or wrong aside, your business case may include circumstances than mean multiple connections are an acceptable solution.

When iterating a data list, although not the greatest performance, it is generally acceptable to execute individual statements that would only affect a single record in a database.

- You might do this to capture specific error information about each row, and in your business logic you will not re-process the rows that did succeed.
- If you need to fail the whole batch when one row fails then you would need to ensure that you use a transaction scope so that you can roll back the entire set.

You would however generally *NOT* create multiple connections. a standard code pattern would be to create a connection *outside* of the loop and re-use the same connection for each transaction.

```
using (var conn =  new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    ...
    start a transaction
    ...
    try
    {
        foreach(var record in dataRecords)
        {
            try
            {
                ...
                Execute your transactions
                ...
            }
            catch(SqlException sx)
            {
                ...
                Process the exception, 
                record relevant information based on the input parameters for this record
                ...
                throw; // or throw a new exception with formatted info...  
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ...
        rollback the transaction
        ...
    }
}
```

A *set-based* approach usually offers greater performance, but that requires a bit of plumbing to set up form a best practises point of view, [this advice from Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67345812/1690217) works well too.

> Multiple transactions, or multiple executions within the same transaction is acceptable, multiple *connections* however should be avoided.

Comment: Thank you, Chris, @Gordon for the help! :) Sorry about the lack of information, I tried to keep it minimal for a purpose (privacy policy). Just started to use SQL recently, but I'm definitely on the right track. With your help I was able to finish my application, even the rollback works fine, so thank you once again for taking the time to help me :) much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should load the Excel table into a table in the database with two columns (at least) called `old_username` and `new_username`.

Then you can run an `update` directly in the database.  You haven't specified the database.  But because of the C# tag, I'll provide SQL Server syntax for the update -- this syntax varies by database:

```
update u
    set username = nc.new_username
    from users u join -- the table you want to update
         name_changes nc
         on u.username = nc.old_username;
```

That is, it is generally better to get the data into the database and do all the work there.